# How to implement login authentication using react-redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jwt

After a bit of research, JWT is commonly used for login authentication because of its compact nature and easiness to parse. I have settled on using JWT. However, my question is on how to embed this in my redux paradigm. Assuming we have a sign up form, when a user fills in his or her credentials and clicks a submit button, this will invoke an action to create an action to create a JWT. Now, this action goes to the back-end of my application and the back-end of my application calls the JWT API? So this action is an asynchronous/rpc call? Also, how does routing happen exactly? I have used react-router before, but using a boilerplate. I am building this web app from scratch and so I am a bit confused on where to deal with the routing and where do I pass this token exactly that I obtain from the server the first time? Is the token used every time a user does a request? How does the client know about this token every time it does the request so that it would keep a user authenticated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a user submits his credentials (email/password) your backend authenticates that for the first time and only this time does the backend use these credentials. On authentication your backend will create a JWT with some of the user information, usually just the user ID. There are plenty of [JWT Libraries](https://jwt.io/#libraries) and even [jwt-decode for javascript](https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode) to do this. The backend will respond with this JWT where the front-end will save it (ie, `localStorage.setItem('authToken', jwt)`) for every subsequent request.

The user will send a request with the JWT in the request header under the `Authorization` key. Something like:

```
function buildHeaders() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('authToken')

    return {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
      "Authorization": `${token}`
    }
}
```

Your backend will now decode and authenticate the JWT. If it's a valid JWT the request continues, if not it's rejected.

Now with React-Router you can protect authenticated routes with the [`onEnter`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#onenternextstate-replace-callback) function. The function you provide does any necessary checks (check localStorage for JWT and if a current user). Typically I've done this:

```
const _ensureAuthenticated = (nextState, replace) => {
    const { dispatch } = store
    const { session } = store.getState()
    const { currentUser } = session
    const token = localStorage.getItem("phoenixAuthToken")
    if (!currentUser && token) {     // if no user but token exist, still verify
      dispatch(Actions.currentUser())
    } else if (!token) {             // if no token at all redirect to sign-in
      replace({
        pathname: "/sign-in",
        state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname}
      })
    }
  }
```

You can use this function in any route like so:

```
<Route path="/secret-path" onEnter={_ensureAuthenticated} />
```

Check out [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/introduction/) for more information on JWT's and the [react-router auth-flow example](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/examples/auth-flow) for more information on authentication with react-router.

Answer (score 3):

I personally use [Redux saga](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga) for async API calls, and I'll show You the flow I've been using for JWT authorization:

1. Dispatch `LOG_IN` action with username and password
2. In your saga You dispatch `LOGGING_IN_PROGRESS` action to show e.x. spinner
3. Make API call
4. Retrieved token save e.x. in localstorage
5. Dispatch `LOG_IN_SUCCESS` or `LOG_IN_FAILED` to inform application what response did You get

Now, I always used a separate function to handle all my requests, which looks like this:

```
import request from 'axios';
import {get} from './persist'; // function to get something from localstorage

export const GET = 'GET';
export const POST = 'POST';
export const PUT = 'PUT';
export const DELETE = 'DELETE';

const service = (requestType, url, data = {}, config = {}) => {
    request.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = get('token') ? `Token ${get('token')}` : '';
    switch (requestType) {
        case GET: {
            return request.get(url, data, config);
        }
        case POST: {
            return request.post(url, data, config);
        }
        case PUT: {
            return request.put(url, data, config);
        }
        case DELETE: {
            return request.delete(url, data, config);
        }
        default: {
            throw new TypeError('No valid request type provided');
        }
    }
};
export default service;
```

Thanks to this service, I can easily set request data for every API call from my app (can be setting locale also).

The most interesting part of it should be this line:

```
request.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = get('token') ? `Token ${get('token')}` : '';`
```

It sets JWT token on every request or leave the field blank.

If the Token is outdated or is invalid, Your backend API should return a response with 401 status code on any API call. Then, in the saga `catch` block, you can handle this error any way You want.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to implement registration and login with React & Redux as well.

Below are a few of the main snippets that implement the login functionality and setting of the http auth header.

This is my **login async action creator** function:

```
function login(username, password) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(request({ username }));

        userService.login(username, password)
            .then(
                user => { 
                    dispatch(success(user));
                    history.push('/');
                },
                error => {
                    dispatch(failure(error));
                    dispatch(alertActions.error(error));
                }
            );
    };

    function request(user) { return { type: userConstants.LOGIN_REQUEST, user } }
    function success(user) { return { type: userConstants.LOGIN_SUCCESS, user } }
    function failure(error) { return { type: userConstants.LOGIN_FAILURE, error } }
}
```

This is the **login function of the user service** that handles the api call:

```
function login(username, password) {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ username, password })
    };

    return fetch('/users/authenticate', requestOptions)
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) { 
                return Promise.reject(response.statusText);
            }

            return response.json();
        })
        .then(user => {
            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
            if (user && user.token) {
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
            }

            return user;
        });
}
```

And this is a helper function used to **set the Authorization header for http requests**:

```
export function authHeader() {
    // return authorization header with jwt token
    let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

    if (user && user.token) {
        return { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + user.token };
    } else {
        return {};
    }
}
```

For the full example and working demo you can go to [this blog post](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/09/16/react-redux-user-registration-and-login-tutorial-example)